# No textures when importing .fbx mode from Sketchfab to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, fbx, 3d-model

The current process of what I have done:

1. Download the .fbx model from Sketchfab
2. When unzipping the file I will generally obtain this structure

- source (with the .fbx)
- Textures

3. Put the unzipped file into my assets in unity

But the model doesn't have textures when it's dragged into the scene

And when I select the model and then click on Materials, it shows:
Location: Use Embedded Materials

Textures: is disabled (Not sure why)

Materials: Extract Materials (If you click on this you can just create a folder with all the materials but no textures)

I have checked several tutorials on YouTube but cannot help

How can I add the texture to the model on unity?

Comment: I had the same exact problem, my imported assets had just a plain single-colored texture instead of the high quality one I had before

Answer (score 1):

In unity as I understand your question well materials created with textures are making final look of an object not the texture in itself. U need to create material and then place it on object
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJaF5DqfJs0
short example

Comment: thanks a lot, now I get it, so I need to manually apply the textures to the materials after importing the 3d model

Comment: Yes exactly and you will have your colourful model